# Do we ever see any visions in the fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In various episodes of *Game of Thrones* we get to see visions, for example, in Qarth, when Daenerys Targaryen enters the House of the Undying, or many of Bran's visions. However, I think there are more mentions of visions seen by the followers of R'hllor than any other vision. However, try as I might, during the times when Melisandre says she is seeing something in the fire, I *never* do. (I'm plodding through all the episodes again, and I've reached season 4, so I'm fairly certain no fire till then shows anything unusual.)

Do we, the audience, ever get to see anything in the fires? If so, when? If not, why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, we don't. First. It is not like they are actually having a vision. They are reading the flames like a gypsy would read a deck of cards, or a witch would read bones or palm reading. Second, it is used to make the audience doubt the reader. We don't see anything because we are supposed to question whether the red woman is actually seeing something or telling the truth. To ask whether she is playing Stannis or not. Had we been shown a vision, then her actions would not be called into question.

Comment: Interesting, but we could still be shown some visions that leave us endlessly debating what they exactly meant (for example, the one with Melisandre in Winterfell, we could have been shown that and be confused just as she was, or the visions she had of Jon Snow when she looked for Azor Ahai)...

Comment: That is to say, we could have be shown her seeing something, but what she saw clearly isn't all that clear, and could have been left unclear. At this point, the power of the priests of the Lord of Light is not in question, so making us doubt whether she saw anything at all doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because then we wouldn't be thinking "is the red woman telling the truth? Is she just using Stannis?" Instead, we would be asking "is the Lord of light using the trustworthy character Mel"? It shifts the doubt unto some abstract higher being instead of the flesh and blood character. The show, and books, are based on the actions of people, not the gods.

Comment: @muru We see Melisandre seeing herself in the mirror at the Wall! Although that really leaves *nothing* to the imagination.